# How to know my wireless card has injection enabled?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, aircrack-ng

I am playing around with aircrack.

And was trying to see whether my wireless card on my laptop can pass the [injection test](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=injection_test&DokuWiki=29f1612f322a75386c2a3855d31acd3e)

And I end up seeing the following... does it mean my wireless card is not able to run aircrack?

```
root@myubuntu:/home/myubuntu# iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:""  Nickname:""
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Tx-Power:24 dBm   
          Retry min limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=5/5  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=-57 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:781  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

root@myubuntu:/home/myubuntu#  aireplay-ng -9 eth1
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Invalid argument

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.  Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start eth1 <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.

root@myubuntu:/home/myubuntu#
```

Comment: Have you tried running `airmon-ng start eth1` and then the test again?

Comment: From my experience, a lot of the older 802.11b cards were able to do injections. I had a lot of trouble with gs and prens.

Comment: See [How to fix ‘ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy ‘ problem. « Taufan Lubis – Ubuntu Linux](http://taufanlubis.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/how-to-fix-ioctlsiocsiwmode-failed-device-or-resource-busy-problem/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the output you displayed above, your current driver **is not** capable of packet injection.  This is because you probably used the default (closed-source) drivers, many of which do not support injection.

You need to use the `compat-wireless` package, to compile your own drivers and use those instead (after uninstalling your current drivers).  See [this page from the Aircrack-ng Wiki](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compat-wireless) which details how to compile your own drivers, as well as patch them to allow packet injection.  At minimum, you need the `mac80211.compat08082009.wl_frag+ack_v1.patch` patch, as detailed in the wiki article linked above.  Note that you should call the [driver select script](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compat-wireless#driver_select) before compiling/installing.

As a side note, these drivers will also change the interface name from `eth1` to `wlan0` (which is also a lot more intuitive name).  Depending on your card, the monitor interface name might be `mon0` (increasing in number with each additional monitoring interface you create with `airmon-ng start`).

Answer (score 3):

```
airmon-ng start eth1
```

This will create a new interface: `mon0`. You can then start your tools pointing to the new interface; i.e.

```
airodump-ng start mon0
```

Though the first poster is correct in saying you have wrong drivers – find the open source drivers that will change your driver name to `wlan0` as the aircrack suite is a wireless pen-testing tool environment. There are other tools for LAN testing.

Answer (score 1):

I was having no injection results. The solution was to invoke airmon as the following: `airmon-ng start wlan0 <channel>`. That will lock the `mon0` interface to the channel `<channel>`. After that, I did a test and I got the result: `Injection is working!`

That is [documented in the wiki](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=injection_test#general):

```
Make sure the card(s) are on the same channel as your AP and locked on
this channel. When putting your card into monitor mode, be sure to specify
the channel via airmon-ng. You can use iwconfig to confirm which channel your
card is currently on. The injection test will fail if your card and access point
are on different channels.

Make sure your card is not channel hopping. A very common mistake is to have
airodump-ng running in channel hopping mode. If you use airodump-ng, be sure 
to use the ”-c <channel>” option. Additionally, ensure all network managers  
and similar are killed off.
```

Answer (score 1):

Running KALI 2.0 (should all download btw) on an old HP 2000

Two wireless cards I use:

1. EDIMAX EW-7811Un - (phy2 wlan1       rtl8192cu   Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n [Realtek RTL8188CUS])

2.ALFA AWUS036NH - (phy3    wlan2       rt2800usb   Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070)

How to fix issue:

1. ifconfig (find the  you would like to use/ place in monitor mode)
2. iwconfig interface (take note if Mode:MANAGED or MONITOR)

   root@h0st:~# iwconfig wlan2

   wlan2     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
         ***Mode:Managed***  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=30 dBm
         Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
         Encryption key:off
         Power Management:off
3. ifconfig (interface) down
4. iwconfig (interface) mode monitor
5. ifconfig (interface) up
6. iwconfig (interface) (to check)

root@h0st:~# ifconfig wlan2 down

root@h0st:~# iwconfig wlan2 mode monitor

root@h0st:~# ifconfig wlan2 up

root@h0st:~# iwconfig wlan2

wlan2     IEEE 802.11bgn  ***Mode:Monitor***  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Tx-Power=30dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

7. airodump the (interface)

root@h0st:~# airodump-ng wlan2

And there you have it! Hope this helps alot of people with the same issues I had.  This places my WLAN2 ALFA into monitor mode.  I could repeat the same process to place my WLAN1 EDIMAX into monitor mode aswell, or just one of them.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I had a similar problem and following your steps I was able to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

..it would appear that your card is in "managed mode".In order to perform the test you will first have to put your card in "monitor" mode ...just search the internet.hope this help.

Comment: It is best not to say "just search for it", if you know where the needed information can be found please post it, or at least provide a link.