# How to get a wireless driver with injection

Tags: wifi-driver, aircrack-ng, packet-injection

Possibly related related:
[How to know my wireless card has injection enabled?](https://superuser.com/questions/301964/how-to-know-my-wireless-card-has-injection-enabled)

NOTE: I do mostly javascript as a programmer, so forgive my noobness, any guidance to how I could have figured this myself would be very appreciated.

Let me start from the end, looks like I do *not* have injection on my drive:

```
$ sudo airmon-ng start wlp3s0


Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
706 avahi-daemon
734 avahi-daemon
765 NetworkManager
1097    wpa_supplicant
4260    dhclient
Process with PID 4260 (dhclient) is running on interface wlp3s0


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlp3s0      Unknown     ath10k_pci - [phy0]
                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)

$ sudo aireplay-ng -9 mon0               
17:18:58  Trying broadcast probe requests...
17:19:00  No Answer...
17:19:00  Found 1 AP 
17:19:00  Trying directed probe requests...
17:19:00  10:FE:ED:8A:EF:D0 - channel: 6 - 'network name'
17:19:06   0/30:   0%
```

The link I posted above suggested this might b due to using closed source wifi driver:

> This is because you probably used the default (closed-source)
>   drivers, many of which do not support injection.
>
> You need to use the compat-wireless package, to compile your own
>   drivers and use those instead ...  as well as patch them to allow packet injection. At minimum, you need the mac80211.compat08082009.wl_frag+ack_v1.patch

My driver is `ath10k_pci`: (I've omitted the Ethernet interface info)

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 32
       serial: c8:ff:28:00:90:51
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless logical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-59-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.0.108 latency=0 link=yes promiscuous=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:127 memory:a1000000-a11fffff
```

Comment: The driver comment is very hardware-specific, and the post you linked to doesn't even say what manufacturer they're talking about! (And it links to a page from 2009.) It may still be true for Broadcom hardware, but certainly not for Atheros.

Comment: @grawity so what other information should I provide?

Comment: @grawity I replaced "card" for driver, thanks for pointing that out!